# Bucket Sort with Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

This is my implentation of Bucket Sort, but I see myself using way too many `for` loops, is this necessary?

```
  public static void bucketSort(Student[] students) {
    final String[] courses = { "IB", "IG", "IN", "IS", "IT" };
    final int amountOfBuckets = courses.length;
    final int n = students.length;

    if (n == 0) return;

    LinkedList<LinkedList<Student>> buckets = new LinkedList<>(); //create buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        buckets.add(new LinkedList<>()); //fill bucketlist with buckets
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getClassNumber().startsWith(courses[i])) {
                buckets.get(i).add(student);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        LinkedList<Student> studentLinkedList = buckets.get(i);
        Student[] s = studentLinkedList.toArray(new Student[studentLinkedList.size()]);
        insertionSortByClass(s);
        studentLinkedList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(s));
        buckets.set(i, studentLinkedList);
    }

    LinkedList<Student> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (LinkedList<Student> bucket : buckets) {
        result.addAll(bucket);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        students[i] = result.get(i);
    }
}
```

As requested:

```
    public static void insertionSortByClass(Student[] student) {
    Student temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < student.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (student[j].compareTo(student[j - 1]) < 0) {
                temp = student[j];
                student[j] = student[j - 1];
                student[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question should describe the problem you are actually trying to solve. I looked at this, and wondered what the purpose of this code is, I gave up.

Comment: Where is `insertionSortByClass()`?

Comment: I have rolled back your previous edit. Please don't invalidate answers by changing your code.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5):

This code seems to be a specific BucketSort made for a specific program. I would instead create a more generic BucketSort:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void bucketSort(E[] array) {
    // ...
}

public static <E> void bucketSort(E[] array, Comparator<E> comparator) {
    // ...
}
```

Note there is two methods; one is for a class that implements the `Comparator` interface, and one to allow a `Comparator` to be passed as the `Comparator` for the class, where there is no comparator, or if you want to compare it in a different way.

Then the only problem is that you don't know the bounds for the buckets; the simple way would be to use bounds provided by the calling method:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void bucketSort(E[] array, E[] separators) {

}

public static <E> void bucketSort(E[] array, E[] separators, Comparator<E> comparator) {

}
```

The separators will be the upper limit of the bucket right before it; and the uppermost bucket will catch everything that is larger than the largest bound.

Now for the actual code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class BucketSort {

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> bucketSort(E[] array,
            E[] separators) {
        Comparator<E> comparator = new Comparator<E>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(E element1, E element2) {
                return element1.compareTo(element2);
            }

        };
        return bucketSort(array, separators, comparator);
    }

    public static <E> List<E> bucketSort(E[] array, E[] separators,
            Comparator<E> comparator) {
        final int numOfBuckets = separators.length + 1;
        // Create Buckets
        // Used ArrayList because we don't need the functions of a LinkedList
        List<Bucket<E>> buckets = new ArrayList<Bucket<E>>(numOfBuckets);
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfBuckets; i++) {
            buckets.add(new Bucket<E>());
        }
        // Sort into Buckets
        for (E element : array) {
            // Use binary search
            buckets.get(bucketNumber(element, separators, comparator)).getItems().add(element);
        }
        // Sort buckets
        for (Bucket<E> bucket : buckets) {
            bucket.getItems().sort(comparator);
        }
        // Combine Buckets and return
        for (int i = 1; i < numOfBuckets; i++) {
            buckets.get(0).getItems().addAll(buckets.get(i).getItems());
        }
        return buckets.get(0).getItems();
    }

    private static <E> int bucketNumber(E element, E[] separators,
            Comparator<E> comparator) {
        return bucketNumber(element, separators, 0, separators.length,
                comparator);
    }

    private static <E> int bucketNumber(E element, E[] separators, int low,
            int high, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        if (low + 1 == high) {
            return low;
        }
        int searchIndex = (high - low) / 2 + low;
        int compareResult = comparator
                .compare(element, separators[searchIndex - 1]);
        if (compareResult == 0) {
            return searchIndex;
        }
        return compareResult < 0 ? bucketNumber(element, separators, low,
                searchIndex, comparator) : bucketNumber(element, separators,
                searchIndex, high, comparator);
    }

}

class Bucket<E> {

    private List<E> elements;

    public Bucket() {
        this.elements = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    public Bucket(Collection<E> elements) {
        this.elements = new LinkedList<E>(elements);
    }

    public List<E> getItems() {
        return elements;
    }

}
```

Yes, I know it looks 10x more complex than it need to be, but this can be used for further applications.

Since you asked for an explanation of the `separators` array...

The separator's array is there so that the method can know where to separate it into buckets. For example:

```
separator = [2, 5, 8, 11]
array = [1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8, 12, 10, 13, 0, 5, 3, 9, 11]
```

Then the buckets would be:

```
buckets = [ [0, 1] , [2, 3, 4] , [5, 6, 7] , [8, 9, 10] , [11, 12, 13] ]
```

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, but thank you for your efforts. I have one question though, what is the use of the seperators array? I am trying to modify your version into a workable version for my needs..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32246/discussion-between-kevin-s-and-thecoffeecup).